# Swift : How to change language inside app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, localization

i am using `Localize-Swift` library ([Link](https://github.com/marmelroy/Localize-Swift)) to localize my application and it works fine with .strings files. the problem is that i have to localize to a language which is right to left and i have to localize via Interface Builder Storyboard so i can make view controllers look right in RTL format. the question is how do i set the storyboard to user selected language in real time ?

for example i have 2 storyboard files :

1- ... /ProjectName/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard

2- ... /ProjectName/fa-IR.lproj/Main.storyboard

how do i switch between them in real time ?

i already know i can change it in Schemes and device language but i want to do it real time and i dont want the users to restart their device.

thanks

Comment: I had the same problem before and I posted the solution that worked with me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37111734/1752899

Answer (score 10, accepted):

found my answer :

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(["language identifier"], forKey: "AppleLanguages") 
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

unfortunately user must restart the app!
if anyone could find a solution to not restart the application please inform me.

Comment: check my comment in your questions. I'm localizing the app without restarting

Comment: @HossamGhareeb . How can we achieve without restarting the app. please can u tell me

Comment: `.synchronize()` is obsolete and should not be used anymore, at all.

Comment: After using this how to get real phone language? I mean we've set `French` via app like mentioned way. but user's phone is in `Spanish`, then how can we get `Spanish`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [NSBundle+Language](https://gist.github.com/narikbi/352e93e446e8b1faf283) third party class.

Comment: your solution is so short, I found it early but didn't try. now after days I tried and I happy.. I used this: https://github.com/maximbilan/ios_language_manager It's exactly the same code (copy paste?!?!) but with additions, no bugs, with examples of usage and a running app. 10 minutes it was implemented in my project =]

Answer (score 3):

In order to change the language without restarting your device you need to switch ‘lproj’ bundle.

You can make it using this code:

```
class L012Localizer: NSObject {
    class func DoTheSwizzling() {
        MethodSwizzleGivenClassName(cls: Bundle.self, originalSelector: #selector(Bundle.localizedString(forKey:value:table:)), overrideSelector:
            #selector(Bundle.specialLocalizedString(key:value:table:)))
    }
}

extension Bundle {
    @objc func specialLocalizedString(key: String, value: String?, table tableName: String?) -> String {
        let currentLanguage = Localization.currentAppleLanguage()
        var bundle = Bundle();
        if let _path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: currentLanguage, ofType: "lproj") {
            bundle = Bundle(path: _path)!
        } else {
            let _path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Base", ofType: "lproj")!
            bundle = Bundle(path: _path)!
        }
        return (bundle.specialLocalizedString(key: key, value: value, table: tableName))
    }
}

func MethodSwizzleGivenClassName(cls: AnyClass, originalSelector: Selector, overrideSelector: Selector){

    let origMethod: Method = class_getInstanceMethod(cls, originalSelector)!;
    let overrideMethod: Method = class_getInstanceMethod(cls, overrideSelector)!;
    if (class_addMethod(cls, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(overrideMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(overrideMethod))) {
        class_replaceMethod(cls, overrideSelector, method_getImplementation(origMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(origMethod));
    } else {
        method_exchangeImplementations(origMethod, overrideMethod);
    }
}
```

Here we are exchanging the implementation of Bundle's localizedString method. Note: we exchanging the Implementation not the reference on the function.

Now add this line in the Appdelegate in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions delegate method.

```
L102Localizer.DoTheSwizzling()
```

After that you need to reload your ViewControllers. In your Main.storyboard set Root View Controller's StoryboardId to "rootnav" and paste this code to your method that switches language:

```
let rootviewcontroller: UIWindow = ((UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window)!)!
rootviewcontroller.rootViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "rootNav")
let mainwindow = (UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window!)!
mainwindow.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: 0.6477, saturation: 0.6314, brightness: 0.6077, alpha: 0.8)
UIView.transition(with: mainwindow, duration: 0.55001, options: .transitionFlipFromLeft, animations: { () -> Void in
}) { (finished) -> Void in
}
```

Comment: How to set our string Key into this function?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. 
It changed App language without restarting app. Thanks a bundle (y)

Comment: In the extension of bundle it showing error as **Use of unresolved identifier 'Localization'; did you mean 'localizations'?** what have to do?

Comment: Answer appears to be based on https://github.com/mmirsat/Localizer/blob/master/Localizer.swift, which has `Localizer.currentAppleLanguage`, which is a wrapper around the standard approach of getting the locale from UserDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [the RSMultiLanguage pod](https://cocoapods.org/?q=lang%3Aswift%20language) is something useful for you? I have used it in my apps and it provides to possibility to change the user language in app. I'm pretty sure you can set it depending on the user location with an if loop. That way you might not have to restart the app.

**RSMultiLanguage**

**Usage**

To run the example project, clone the repo, and run pod install from the Example directory first.

**Installation**

RSMultiLanguage is available through CocoaPods. To install it, simply add the following line to your Podfile:

```
pod "RSMultiLanguage"
```

**Author**

Roy Ng, roytornado@gmail.com

**License**

RSMultiLanguage is available under the MIT license. See the LICENSE file for more info.

Answer (score 0):

1. Requires restart of app. Follow below lines of code.

   UserDefaults.standard.set(["language identifier"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
   UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
2. Restart of app not requires ( the answer may requires customization in provided source code). Follow the provided web link.

http://www.factorialcomplexity.com/blog/2015/01/28/how-to-change-localization-internally-in-your-ios-application.html