# How to update the language immediately in my application on the current page

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

**How can I switch language between applications in an efficient and simple way?**

My current practice is to write a Singleton

There is a way to reset the rootViewController in a single instance

**This approach if the root view of the different circumstances, how to dynamically reset**

For example, the root view is of type UIViewController or UITabBarController

**There are several flaws in the way to reset the root view**

1. sometimes can not stay in the switch language page

For example, the root view is a UIViewController, and the page into the toggle language is UITabController

2. if it is UITabBarController, viewControllers page, a large number of data requests, and switch the language will re-request, it is obviously very unreasonable

---

- Another approach is to use NotificationCenter, but this approach I
  think in my entire application need to register a lot of Notification
  is not suitable for large-scale use

---

**I hope you can guide me about how to do the application of switching language,  I can use either Objective-C or Swift**

**If there is a better way to tell me
Thank you very much**

Comment: Why don't you register your singleton instances or any other instance to a certain callback lets say an Array holding instances that implement a certain delegate "changeLanguage:" or something and when you change the language all delegates will get informed about the update? --> LanguageCallbackHandler with NSArray<LanguageUpdateDelegate *> *languageUpdateCallbacks and the delegate/protocol that will require the related delegate to implement the "update" function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift : How to change language inside app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37111409/swift-how-to-change-language-inside-app)

Comment: Can you say more detail? Or give some example code

MultiLanguage.shared.callBack {([LanguageUpdateDelegate]) in

} Is it like this? and how it should be done