# How to change the language of iOS app using objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to change the language of iOS app using objective-c? I made the iOS app using objective-c. It is used localized feature for string about English and French. If iPhone's language setting is based on French, my app is running with French, if iPhone's language setting is based on English, my app is running with English.
But I don't want to change the iPhone's language setting. I want to change the language inside my app. I tried to find out the solutions, but still didn't find it out.
What is the correct solution?

Comment: Redirect user into system's app settings. There is also language switcher just for particular application since iOS 13.

Comment: @ATEC HUO Please check link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37111409/swift-how-to-change-language-inside-app

Comment: Thank you for your quotes, @RahulPhate, But I am doing the iPhone app using Objective-c. And also at the link what you suggested, what is correct answer?

Comment: Thank you, @Cy-4AH, But I can't find the switcher what you mentioned. How can I do it programmatically?

Comment: call openURL with UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString and you will see screen with language switcher